# Capitalise any words with less than five characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How can I capitalise abbreviations if equal or less than 4 letters in column A?

I couldn't find on web anything treating abbreviations specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UCASE("string") will work.

```
Sub stringtest()
If Len(Range("A1")) < 5 Then
Range("A1") = UCase(Range("A1"))
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you KenSquare. Works great :)

Comment: Why it's not covering entire Column A?

Comment: To do that you'll need to loop through Column A.  I don't have time to demonstrate right now, but I will try later.

Comment: I was wondering if the macro will capitalize anything less than 5 characters even if a cell contains more than one word? For instance, what if a cell has a text combination of: "Ab Cdef Ghi"? Can it capitalize "Ab" only, leaving the rest as it?

Comment: Just saw this part of the question, let me think about that!

Comment: OK Munir, here is a loop to do what you need.  Make sure you go through and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

In a single shot with an array (for *A1:A50000*) use the worksheet function `Proper`:

```
[a1:A50000] = Application.Evaluate("=IF(len(A1:A50000)<5,Proper(A1:a50000),a1:a50000)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with a loop.  This assumes that each cell in column A will have something in it until you are done - it will stop on the first empty cell in column A.

```
Sub initCaps()
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim aryWords() As String
Dim firstWord As String
Dim strNew As String
intRow = 1

Do Until Range("A" & intRow) = ""'Look for a blank call in A, then stop.
    aryWords() = (split(Range("A" & intRow), " "))'Make an array of the cell.
    firstWord = aryWords(0)'Get the first word.

    If Len(firstWord) < 5 Then'Test the first word length.
        firstWord = UCase(firstWord)'Change it to upper case.
        strNew = firstWord & " "'Add a space to re-build the string
             If UBound(aryWords()) > 0 Then
                For I = 1 To UBound(aryWords())
                strNew = strNew & aryWords(I) & " "'Put back the rest of the words.
                Next
             End If
           Range("A" & intRow) = strNew'Put it back into the cell, modified.
           Erase aryWords()
            firstWord = ""
            strNew = ""
      Else
            Erase aryWords()'Clean up.
            firstWord = ""
            strNew = ""
     End If
intRow = intRow + 1
Loop'Do it again!
End Sub
```

Good Luck!

Comment: It's a superb piece of code, works flawlessly and does what it's suppose to do. Thanks a lot KenSquare for your time. So nice of you :)